# How to interpret SDP payloads of SIP responses?

Tags: sip, sdp

I conceptually understand the SDP message when it's delivered in the body of a SIP request.  However, given that SIP responses can contain their own SDP message, I find myself wondering whether or not this means that the given SDP message is what the receiver of the request actually did or not.

Consider for instance that an INVITE is received with a=inactive and the peer responds with a=inactive.  Does this mean that the peer sending the response actually chose to make the media type inactive.

In general, does the SDP request convey how the sender will configure its media services and the response convey how the receiver will configure its media services?

Comment: Have you read [RFC 3264 "An Offer/Answer Model with the Session Description Protocol (SDP)"](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3264) yet?

Comment: I have not.  Thanks very much for the resource.  I will have a look.